# Correct file name extension for MIME 'text/enriched' file format?

Tags: emacs, mime, richtext, .doc

Emacs offers the ability to use the MIME standard `text/enriched` for writing enriched text. What is the canonical file name extension for this format. Emacs seems to think it's `.doc` (see `$EMACSDIR/24.1/etc/enriched.doc`), but this could be confused with the more common Microsoft Word `.doc` format. Is there an alternative?

(I know it's not `.rtf`, which is a format different from both Microsoft's `.doc` and MIME's `text/enriched` formats)

EDIT:

It seems that `.etf` and `.txte` are some accepted extensions for this file type.

Comment: Where in Emacs do you see .doc associated with text/enriched?  In Emacs 24.1, ".docx?" is associated with doc-view-mode-maybe, for viewing MS Office files via OpenOffice PDF generation tools.

Comment: In the Info node `(emacs) Enriched Text`, there's reference to a file `$EMACSDIR/24.1/etc/enriched.doc`, itself in `text/enriched` format, which demonstrates the capabilities of Emacs's `Enriched Mode`.

Comment: Yes, this follows an old convention to name documentation text files as .doc. Emacs doesn't actually use the file extension to identify text/enriched files, it uses the first line of the file - try find-file-literally on enriched.doc to see.

Answer (score 2):

`text/enriched` is also known as `Enriched Text Format` or `.etf`.

http://users.starpower.net/ksimler/eudora/etf.html

http://filext.com/file-extension/ETF

Answer (score 1):

Due to its intended use as an inline mail format, I don't think there is a standard file extension for it. `.txte` seems to be another extension that is used for it though, which does not clash with other well-known formats.

Comment: thanks JSON. I haven't ever seen `.txte` before. Could you link a reference?

Comment: I got it from a search on "mime.types text/enriched", which turned up a lot of mime.types files that do not assign any file extension to it and an example on this page: http://stuff.mit.edu/faq/mimetypes.html